# How to remove the horizontal line at the origin?

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to remove the horizontal line that is located at the origin, but I can't do it. Do you have any idea how to do it? I will thank you too much.

```
Clear[ShannonP];
ShannonP ={{1,2.42},{2,-0.75},{3,-2.18},{4,-3.14},{5,0.47},{6,-1.45},{7,-2.63}, {8,-0.74},{9,-2.10457},{10,-1.63802}};
"ListPlot[datos,PlotRange->Automatic]";

Clear[plotSP];
plotSP=ListLinePlot[{ShannonP},
   PlotRange -> {{1, 10}, {-3.5, 3.5}},
   PlotStyle->{Red, Thickness[0.003]}, 
   PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 5},
   Frame->True,
   FrameStyle->Directive[Black, 11],
   FrameTicks->{{{-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3},None},{{{1,"1s"},{2,"2s"},{3,"3s"},{4,"4s"},{5,"2p"},{6,"3p"},{7,"4p"},{8,"3d"},{9,"4d"},{10,"4f"}},None}},
   ImageSize->Large
 ];
```

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 4):

> I'm trying to remove the horizontal line that is located at the origin

One possibility might be to use `Axes->False`

```
ShannonP = {{1, 2.42}, {2, -0.75}, {3, -2.18}, {4, -3.14}, {5, 
    0.47}, {6, -1.45}, {7, -2.63}, {8, -0.74}, {9, -2.10457}, {10, \
-1.63802}};
plotSP = ListLinePlot[{ShannonP},
  PlotRange -> {{1, 10}, {-3.5, 3.5}},
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.003]},
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 5},
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(D\),\(nl\)]\)(p)", 
    "Incertidumbre"},
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 11], 
  FrameTicks -> {{{-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3}, 
     None}, {{{1, "1s"}, {2, "2s"}, {3, "3s"}, {4, "4s"}, {5, 
       "2p"}, {6, "3p"}, {7, "4p"}, {8, "3d"}, {9, "4d"}, {10, "4f"}},
      None}},
  ImageSize -> Large, Axes -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]